# Solr Import via ModifiableSolrParams with security credentials

Tags: java, solr, solrj, dataimporthandler

I'm trying to execute import via java using ModifiableSolrParams:

Can you please point me on the right direction or reference on how to add security credentials (username / password) to trigger the import.

Current code

```
    SolrServer server = new HttpSolrServer(baseurl);

    ModifiableSolrParams params = new ModifiableSolrParams();
    params.set("command", "full-import");
    params.set("clean", "true");
    params.set("commit", "true");

    QueryRequest request = new QueryRequest(params);
    request.setPath("/dataimport");

    server.request(request);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add HttpRequestInterceptor to you HttpServer. This interceptor will be able to add authorization header to every your request.

For cloud Solr the util class that allow to do this is HttpClientUtil. You can start from this class, or check where in HttpSolrServer is actually HttpClient present.

Comment: Will check this. I see a lot of solutions with preemptive authentications but can't seem to make it work. I added the following parameters to the above solution   
     params.set(HttpClientUtil.PROP_BASIC_AUTH_USER,"USER");
  
  
  
  params.set(HttpClientUtil.PROP_BASIC_AUTH_PASS,"PASSWORD"); But i'm getting the following error

Comment: This is the error i am getting: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException$ErrorCode.getErrorCode(I)Lorg/apache/solr/common/SolrException$ErrorCode;

Answer (score 1):

I veered away from Solrj and went with this approach instead.

```
HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
String userpass = usr + ":" + pwd;

HttpPost httpGet = new HttpPost(dataimport_cmd);
String encoding = 
DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(userpass.getBytes("UTF-8"));
httpGet.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);

    Client.execute(httpGet);
```